# Does showing a flashing time separator slow down a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, performance, clock

Is there any reason to be concerned that showing flashing time separators would slow down my Mac, since the computer now has to keep flashing the separator? What about showing seconds? Why or why not?

[image]

Comment: It won't impact your computer performance, but keep in mind it might be distracting and decrease your personal performance :)

Comment: Wtf is with all these downvotes? Serious question!

Comment: I think it's a joke that your question got downvoted. It's a serious question and it piqued my interest too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No.

The menubar is controlled by the process `SystemUIServer`. It requires little performance with "flash the time separators" enabled.

There are other processes which are more significant for the CPU performance.

[image]

This screenshot is taken with *flashing time separators* and *show seconds* enabled.

You can easily verify this by resetting the menubar using:

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will do any harm. You Mac is using seconds anyway, only now he will actually display them. And about the flashing seperator, I would be too concerned about that either.

Basically, showing something on the display is a matter of turning pixels on and of. So your Mac has only work a tiny bit harder to turn those pixels on and off again. Maybe, their will be a very very very slight less battery performance, but nothing that will really slow down your Mac I guess.